# noob trying to make the bad guy explode in a Flash game

Tags: flash, movieclip

Forgive me for my noobyness on this (I am new to Flash), but I have searched everywhere for 3 days to find this, and I have tried so many different things, and nothing seems to work. This should be simple...

scenario: simple game, the player fly's through space shooting bad guys.
(my starting steps where this great tutorial: http://www.makeflashgames.com/tutorials/tut4.php )

I now would like to make my enemies explode when a collision is detected. I have made a new movieclip with my explosion animation, dropped that movieclip into a frame on my Enemy movieclip. This frame I labeled Explode.

On the GameController.as I went down to the code for removing the Enemy when a bullet collision is detected, and removed the removechild code, and replaced it with:
Enemy.gotoAndPlay("Explode");
this gives me error     1061: Call to a possibly undefined method gotoAndPlay through a reference with static type Class.

I've tried _root.Enemy.gotoAndPlay("Explode");
it didn't work (I read _root doesn't work in as3)

What am I missing?

the code I wrote is in a few different area's.
in the gamecontroller.as i have

```
        for (var i=bullets.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            for (var j=enemies.length - 1; j >= 0; j--)
            {
                if (bullets[i].hitTestObject(enemies[j].collisionArea))
                {

                    playerScore +=  enemies[j].getPointsWorth();

                    mcGameStage.removeChild(bullets[i]);
                    bullets.splice(i,1);

                    Enemy.gotoAndPlay("Explode");

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

If I remove the gotoandplay, and just put in a

mcGameStage.removeChild(enemies[j]);
                        enemies.splice(j,1);

then the game runs fine (without the explosion animation)

@Sunil D.:
Your code works like a charm. It has, however , left me with a new problem. I need to remove my enemy when the Explode animation finishes (frame 35)
I tried this code

```
enemy.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,checkFrame);

function checkFrame(event:Event):void
    {
        if (enemy.currentFrame  ==  35)
            {
                  mcGameStage.removeChild(enemies[j]);
                  enemies.splice(j,1);
                  enemy.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,checkFrame);
            }
    }
```

This is giving me Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null.
    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/removeChild()
    at MethodInfo-243()

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're getting is that when you do `Enemy.gotoAndPlay("Explode");` you're trying to call the `gotoAndPlay()` method on the `Enemy` class itself. Instead, you need to call the `gotoAndPlay()` method on an **instance** of the Enemy class.

From the code you have shown, it looks like you have instances of the `Enemy` class in your `enemies` array (it's an array of `Enemy` objects). So you probably should be able to explode the enemy by doing this:

```
var enemy:Enemy = enemies[j] as Enemy;
enemy.gotoAndPlay("Explode");
```

Comment: Right. Thank you. I didn't understand the difference there, but now that you say it, it makes sense.